# Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::createTextNode()

Tags: php, xml, file, domdocument, edi

I get the message  Call to undefined method DOMElement::createTextNode() .

My xml file has the tag entries, which have various entryresult tags inside with number and title

My code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('results.xml');
$student = $dom->documentElement;
$studentinfo = $student->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0);
$newName = $student->createTextNode('Book1'); 
$student->replaceChild($newName, $student); 
$dom->saveXML();
```

I want to get to entries->entryresult->title for a given number , edit the name of the title (for example bookA to bookB) and save it.

Answer (score 3):

The `create*()` methods are part of the `DOMDocument`, not the element nodes.

```
$newName = $dom->createTextNode('Book1');
```

If you don't have the document in the current context you can read it from `DOMNode::$ownerDocument`.

```
$newName = $student->ownerDocument->createTextNode('Book1');
```